# Creating a Published drop down in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

```
<field
    name="published"
    type="list"
    label="JSTATUS"
    description="JFIELD_PUBLISHED_DESC"
    class="inputbox"
    filter="intval"
    size="1"
    default="1"
>
    <option value="1">
        JPUBLISHED</option>
    <option value="0">
        JUNPUBLISHED</option>
    <option value="-2">
        JTRASHED</option>
</field>
```

I've created a Joomla dropdown in my form.xml file of a custom component to choose the published status of the item. I've taken this code unashamedly from the Joomla `com_content` component (and copied and pasted it into my own `form.xml` file. However when its rendered in the `edit.php` file (as shown below) you can see that the item is being set as unpublished. Despite the code above clearly setting the default as 1 which should correspond to published. Any good ideas as to why/how to fix this. I can easily change the drop down back from unpublished to published - and it works fine doing that. But its just annoying and a bug I'd like to fix. Any ideas?

[image: This shows the module being unpublished by default]

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with your code. Does it do the same if you shuffle the options around and/or leave out the `filter`? Also, iirc `list` fields don't have a `size` attribute.

Comment: I've tried shuffling the options round with no success (initially I had unpublished at the top but then changed the order round to see if it made a difference). The `size` is there on the `article.xml`for com_content - but your right on second thoughts - can't see it doing anything so will remove that later. Just tried removing the `filter` and didn't make any difference. I should add though that the drop down itself functions perfectly. I can select trashed, published or unpublished and it sets those values. Its just the default value that fails on a new item.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look if there is any override through your code, since this was taken by the com_content component, it won't set to default until all the mandatory fields are set, double check if any JS script or PHP function interrupts your field's normal behavior.

Another thought of mine is that maybe there is a problem with the translations, so take a close look to the translation files.

Comment: Hi, I should add I have just copied the form field into my own components `form.xml` file (and changed the name from status to published and removed the 'Archived' Option). There isn't any custom js in my component (just the default Joomla stuff) - I'm not even running any rules yet. There shouldn't be any php fields that I'm aware of - I'm trying to keep my component as simple as possible for now! I will check the language files - nice idea. Although if JPublished is translating as unpublished for my module and published for `com_content` would be very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a table / model approach like com_content does? if so, when the record doesn't exist, its fields will be set to default (as read from database, so int fields will default to 0).

You can either

- set the right defaults in the database,
- check their values in the model,
- change JPUBLISHED to 0 and JUNPUBLISHED to 517

although the latter looks really ugly.

Comment: Yes indeed I am. I guess this always needs to be stored in the database. Interesting. Whats the point of the default value in the form field then if it then reads from the database? I suppose it makes sense though as `null`/`0` would be the default value in the database for a new field. Easy fix to change the default in the database - will try his tonight - thanks!!

Comment: Ok I set the default database value to be 1 and it made no difference unfortunately. Still shows unpublished as the default option. Also just looking at com_weblinks and com_content I can see in their fb tables the default value for them is 0 not 1.

Comment: then you definitely need to do this in the view, before you bind the form to the data, set the data defaults.

Comment: How do I do this? As far as I was aware in view.html.php I needed `  $this->item = $this->get('Item');` and in the edit.php i needed `    <li><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('state'); echo $this->form->getInput('state'); ?></li>` again as used in the core components. I can't see any other use anyhow :/